# In a loop, different strings read are being repeated as the same string in the end

Tags: c, string, strtok

To explain it better, I have a struct "user" with a user ID, their name and an array with their friends IDs. A loop reads a file as input in which each line contains information about the user, in this model: "ID;name;friendsID", and a user might have more than one friend (in this case it is "ID;name;friendID1;...;friendIDx").

I tried to read each line por each user, counting how many ";" there are to know how many friends the user has, and using strtok to get the user ID, name, and friend's IDs. Everything worked, except the names. It reads each name correctly, but somehow, ate the end of the loop, every user has the same name, the last name read.

I have no idea why is it doing that if it reads and atributes the name string correctly inside the loop.

This is what I've got so far:

```
typedef struct user {
   int ID;
   char* name;
   int* friendsID;
}; 

// declaring variables, declaring user array, opening file, allocating memory, etc.

for(i = 0; i < num_users; i++){
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), input); // Reads a line
    for(j = 0, user_friends = 0; line[j]; j++) { // Counts how many friends the user has
       user_friends += (line[j] == ';');
    }
    user[i].ID = atoi(strtok(line, ";")); // Reads the ID
    user[i].name = strtok(NULL, ";"); // Reads the name
    for(k = 0; k < user_friends - 1; k++) { // Reads the friend's IDs
       user[i].friendsID[k] = atoi(strtok(NULL, ";")); 
    }
}
```

At the end, I have all the right ID and friend's IDs, but the names are all the same.

Comment: More code, including type definitions, would help...

Comment: `line` is overwritten on each call to `fgets`. Since `user[i].name` is a pointer to a token in `line`, they will all point to the last `line` read. (if `ID`'s were of different length, then they would point to different parts of the last line)

Comment: I bet `user[i].name` is not a string. What is the type of `user[i].name`?

Comment: Oh, it makes sense now. So I'd have to use a diferent "line" each time, then?

Comment: Or at least `user[i].name = strdup (strtok(NULL, ";"));` (you will be responsible for `free`ing each `user[i].name` later) There is nothing wrong with using the same `line`, you just need to make a copy to preserve each `user[i].name`. You must also allocate for `friendsID[k]`

Comment: Ah, yes, that'd be more practical. Thank you.

Comment: Make a copy of the name string to assign to `user[i].name`, and allocate space for the `friendsID` array prior to assigning values to its elements (eg. `user[i].friendsID = malloc(user_friends * sizeof(*user[i].friendsID));`).  Also wouldn't hurt to add error checks... and, you'll need to add some way of storing the number of elements in `friendsID` so you can refer to it later.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks. And I just didn't put the error checks in here because I thought it would make the code less legible, but I agree. And ah, good point...

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of areas where the code may invoke undefined behavior. First, just a nit, but the `*` goes with the variable, not the type, e.g.:

```
typedef struct user {
    int ID;
    char *name;
    int *friendsID;
};
```

This generally protects against declarations like:

```
int* a, b, c;    /* b and c are NOT pointers */
```

In your code, you can hardcode the `';'` for `strtok` if you like, but you are better served either creating a constant or a variable holding your *delimiter* so if you need to adjust it, you do it only in one place.

Note, as you have both `name` and `friendsID`, they are both *uninitialized pointers* and have no storage for multiple characters or integers. You must dynamically allocate storage for any string or array of ints you intend to store in either.

There is no need for `for (i = 0; i < num_users; i++)`. As you have explained, you have one set of data for a `user` on each line, so just read all the lines, unless you absolutely need to limit your reads to a specific number of lines. In case you want to read all lines, a simple `while (fgets (line, sizeof line, input))` is all you need.

As mentioned in the comments, and as shown below, you need to validate each read and each token you take from the line. The easiest way is to ***check the return*** as you should be doing with each function call.

In the event you have `friendsID`'s present, you need a way to (1) test if there are any, and (2) allocate/reallocate as needed until all have been read. Below is one approach to your problem based on the limited information posted. It uses `idx` for the `user` index and `fidx` as the `friendsID` index (I'm not that creative). Putting the pieces together, you could do something like the following. Read through the snippet and look at how the logic is structured. (**note:** this is just an example, for which no data has been posted) Let me know if you have any questions.

```
char *delim = ";\n";
int idx = 0, fidx = 0, nfriends = 10;

/* line must be declared as a character array (not pointer) to use sizeof
 * (only add record if both ID and name present)
 */

while (fgets (line, sizeof line, input)) {
    char *p = strtok (line, delim);
    if (p)  /* valid token for ID? */
        user[idx].ID = atoi (p);
    else {
        /* throw error */
        continue;
    }
    if ((p = strtok (NULL, delim)))  /* valid token for name? */
        user[idx].name = strdup (p);
    else {
        /* throw error */
        continue;
    }
    if ((p = strtok (NULL, delim))) { /* is there a friendsID? */
        /* allocate for nfriends */
        user[idx].friendsID = calloc (nfriends, sizeof *(user[idx].friendsID));
        if (!user[idx].friendsID) {
            /* memory exhausted, throw error */
            break;
        }
        user[idx].friendsID[fidx++] = atoi (p);  /* assign 1st ID */
        while ((p = strtok (NULL, delim))) {     /* loop for all remaining */
            user[idx].friendsID[fidx] = atoi (p);
            if (fidx++ == nfriends) {            /* check against limit */
                /* realloc user[idx].friendsID to 
                 * 2 * nfriends * sizeof *(user[idx].friendsID)
                 * nfriends *= 2
                 */
            }
        }
        /* optional -- realloc user[idx].friendsID to
         * fidx * sizeof *(user[idx].friendsID) for exact size
         */
    }
    idx++;  /* increment user index */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the throughout answer! This is quite interesting, I'll try to implement something like this later (it's quite late here now). The only thing I'd add is that in the file, there'll be more information below the lines about the users. Actually, the first line is the numver of users, so then I can know how many lines there'll be about the users (ID, name, and friends). So that's why I used that "for". Sorry for not being quite clear, next time I ask a question here a have learned my lesson.

Comment: Sure, that is 100% OK, that's why I dropped the note (*"if it is absolutely necessary"*). Then you can simply read the line and do `while (nlines < limit && fgets (line, sizeof line, input)) { ... nlines++; }` That will take care of limiting the number of lines you process to `limit`.